# HighCharts add div to series on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I have high charts, in charts when clicked on each bar I would like to create a popup for that I am using jquery balloon pop up plugin. Here is the code

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                slicedOffset: 0,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                stacking: 'normal',
                point: {
                    events: {

                        click: function (e) {
                            $(e).showBalloon({
                           contents: 'Hello'
                           });
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It doesn't work says SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported. I thought it would be better to add normal HTML element ( add div to the series on click) and perform bubble on it, but I am unable add div to it. Here is the code for that,

```
  $(e).append("<div>hello world</div>");
```

But it says SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'createDocumentFragment': object is null or undefined. Can any body help me finding the mistake please ?

I was able to show balloon pop up using this,

```
  $($(e.target)).showBalloon({
        contents: '<div ng-controllrt="chartController"<a href="javascript::void(0)" ng-click="test()"> Click </a></div>'
    });
```

But the problem is the tool tip is never been under angular scope, it's outside the scope. I will try to post a fiddle soon. But, to understand the code structure here is how is done, here is the chart config is seperate js file,

```
var chartService = function($rootScope){

var setConfig = function(chartData,$scope){
  $roorScope.chartConfig = {


  chart: { // options}

  };

plotOptions: {
            series: {
                slicedOffset: 0,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                stacking: 'normal',
                point: {
                    events: {

                        click: function (e) {
                            $(e).showBalloon({
                           contents: 'Hello'
                           });
                        }
                    }
                }
};
return {
setConfig: function(chartData,$scope){
return setConfig(chartData,$scope);
}
};
};
```

In my controller I inject this as service and call the setConfig

```
var myController = function ($rootScope,){

 chartService.setConfig(data,$scope);

//this is the scope function I wanted to execute whenever user clicks on the       anchor link in the jquery Balloon Pop Up

$scope.test = function () {
alert("test");
}; 
};
```

But the click never happens , can anybody suggest me what might be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Although it is not an efficient way to do it. It is working.
You need to iterate though all the points and toggle off balloon. So, The iteration and **toggling off the balloon** can be achieved by using `sibling` and `hideBalloon`,

```
 $(e.target).siblings().each(function () {
    $(this).hideBalloon();
 });
```

And for the initialization part it is same as you have mentioned in your question. So, the code looks as follows,

```
 click: function (e) {
           $(e.target).siblings().each(function () {
                  $(this).hideBalloon();
           });
           $(e.target).showBalloon({
                  classname: "balloonTip",
                  contents: 'Hello'
           });
        },
```

#### And here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjLhoyyb/1/).

Comment: Thank you @Runcorn. I figured it last night but there is another problem I have updated the question, it is some sort of scope issue now.